# Игра поле чудес

Tags: python

**Доброго времени суток, Добрые кодеры!
Помогите своими знаниями, пожалуйста.
Как можно доработать мой код касательно задания и где есть ошибки?**

**Задание:**
Написать упрощённую версию игры, которая запускается в консоли для одного игрока.

**Часть 1**

Опишите логику программы используя декомпозицию задачи.
За каждое действие должна отвечать своя функция. Помните, что функция должна выполнять одну какую-либо задачу.

У вас должно получиться нечто такое:

```
current_word = get_word()
table = create_table(current_word)
live = get_lives()
```

**Часть 2**

Расширьте функционал игры:
Предложите игроку после каждого тура сыграть ещё или отказаться
Подумайте, будет ли количество жизней восстанавливается перед началом каждого тура?
Предложите игроку выбрать уровень сложности текущей игры.

**Что получилось у меня:**

```
gdifficult_task=input('Добро пожаловать в игру "Поле чудес"!\nЧтобы начать игру, нажмите "Enter".\n')
def maskWord(st, wd, ggs):

    result = ''
    gg = []
    ch = ''
    for ch in st:
        if not ch == '■ ':
            if not ch in gg:
                gg.append(ch)

    if not ggs in gg:
        gg.append(ggs)

    for ggs in wd:
        if ggs in gg:
            result += ggs
        else: 
            result += " ■ "
    if False:
        print ('st %s') % st
        print ('wd %s') % wd
        print ('ggs %s') % ggs
        print (gg)

    return result
wd = 'ithub' # загаданное слово
st = ' False■ ' * len(wd)
lv = 0 #кол-во попыток

play = True
while play:
    if lv == len(wd)*1: #Здесь, мы выдаем жизни, они зависят ок кол-ва букв в слове и число на которое мы умножаем. 
        print ('\nВы проиграли.') #проигрыш 
        play = False
    ggs = input('Назовите букву?\n ')
    lv +=1 #при =1 бесконечная игра.
    st = maskWord(st, wd, ggs)
    print (st)
    print('Номер вашей попытки:')
    print (int(lv))
    if maskWord(st, wd, ggs) == wd:  
        print ('Изи вин, изи лайф')  #победа
        play = False
```

Comment: Количество жизней)) смертельная игра)

Comment: и что не так в ходе выполнения кода?

Comment: 1.  для начала вместо `play = False` напишите `break`, тогда не будет приглашения с лишней фразой "номер вашей попытки".
2. сбивается формат когда буква угадана  =  некрасиво.
3. вводимые буквы надо бы приводить к нижнему регистру
4. не помню правил "поле чудес", но кажется, если человек угадал букву, то "жизнь" не сгорает...